# Upgrading to WooCommerce 3.1 not available?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My website is using WooCommerce 2.6.14, so I thought I should update to WooCommerce 3.1. The weird thing is that I don't see "Update now" button in the Plugins admin page:

[Plugins page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csdat.png)

And I can't manually update WooCommerce by overwriting the folder in FTP because it's not visible!

[FTP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJK3c.png)

Any idea how can I update WooCommerce?

Answer (score 0):

1. First back-up your WordPress site if you haven’t already.
2. Download a ZIP file of the plugin you need to upgrade.
3. Use FTP to delete the existing plugin directory from the wp-content/plugins/ directory on your site.
4. Replace the deleted directory by uploading the unzipped plugin to the wp-content/plugins/ directory leaving it in a directory that looks like (for example) wp-content/plugins/plugin-name

5.Sign in to your WordPress site. Go to the ‘Plugins’ menu and verify that the plugin you upgraded is the newest version.